# Backbone: check if View is closed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, x-editable

***What I have:***

I have a *edit* function in which I rerender my view;

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    edit: function (view) {
      ......
      view.render();
    }
});
```

***What a problem:***

There is an usecase in which during *edit* function view can be closed, so I MUST NOT invoke `view.render()` at the end of *edit* function.

***Question:***

How to check if view has already been closed inside *edit* function? Something like:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    edit: function (view) {
      ......
      if (!view.isClosed()) 
          view.render();
    }
});
```

***For @net.uk.sweet:***

I use Bootstrap X-Editable. With help of it I can modify test fields. To modify text field I just need to click on it, change value, and then click outside of it (outside of text field). In such case method *success* will be invoked.

```
textEditor: function(view) {               
            $(this).editable({
                type: 'textarea',
                mode: 'inline',
                onblur: 'submit',
                showbuttons: false,
                inputclass: 'edit-comments-text-input',
                validate: function(value) {
                    if (!value.trim()) {
                        return 'Can not be empty!';
                    }
                },
                success: function(response, newValue){
                    //modify the comment
                    comment.text = newValue.trim();
                    //rerender
                    if (!view.isClosed()) //This line is what I need, but view hasn't isClosed method ((
                        view.render();
                }
            });
}
```

Also it is worth to say that user can close view by clicking on close button or by clicking outside of view.

**Problem use case:**

1. User click on x-editable field
2. Change text
3. Click close button

**What happens in such case:**

Two actions:

1. View is closed
2. *success* method, which invoke `view.render()`, BUT MUST NOT!

**Summary:**

I need to check inside of my *success* method if view has been closed.

***Coarse solution:***

Seems I find some solition, not the best one, of course.

```
if ($(view.el).hasClass('in'))
   view.render();
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to help. How about posting the whole of your view class? Or even better, put a demo together in http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Please, see "for @net.uk.sweet"  section of my question

Comment: @NickoleAbs Is there a problem in keepin a flag `.isClosed` on view (and modifying it when needed)?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet flags is a bad practice, and are error prone. My view is closed from many places, and I need to reset flag each time. And someone may forget...

Comment: @net.uk.sweet see "coarse solution" section of my question

Comment: I don't see why a flag is bad practice, and relying on the stylesheet for application state is surely worse. Add a close method on your view  and when it is called, set a closed property of the view to true. Your isViewClosed method can then return that value. Any code which needs to close the view uses the close method.

Comment: If your view instance is still accessible, if it hasn't been destroyed, why not just keep an instance variable in the view object itself. It can be accessed with `view.setClosed(true)` and `view.setClosed(false)`.

Comment: @NickoleAbs how is the view "closed"? Depending on how it is "closed", i.e. if it's done via CSS, or removing the element from the DOM entirely, then you can achieve this in different ways.

Comment: Why "close" the view? Why not simply destroy it with a [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) call?

Comment: I'll try to answer all your questions. 1) Relying on the stylesheet isn't the worse, since stylesheet is ruled by boostrap and I don't change it anywhere. 2) I close view but it can be reopened at any moment. So I just hide the view on close and doesn't even destroy DOM element. When I open my view I just rerender it. 3) Despite of all, I don't want to use flags. It isn't the single point in my application, where I am tempted to make one more flag. And I don't to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {
        this.setClosed(false);
    },

    setClosed : function(booleanValue) {
        this.closed = booleanValue;
    },

    getClosed : function() {

        return this.closed;

    },

    edit: function () {

        var view = this;
        //......
        if (!view.getClosed()) {
            view.render();
        }
    }
});
```